# The target device does not support the 'run-as' command

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not able to debug my app. When I press debug button in Android Studio, I get this message which tells me:

> The target device does not support the 'run-as' command:

[image: target device does not supoort run as command]

The Learn more link leads me to [Here](http://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/instant-run.html) but I cant see anything that helps me to fix the issue.

On my device I see a dialog with this message:

> Application is waiting for debugger to attach

**And the app does not start !!!**

[image: Application is waiting for debugger to attach]

**What I tried so far :**

1. Perform Clean and Rebuild
2. Restart Android Studio and Device

I not sure this problem related to my device(Samsung Galaxy A7) or not, But I remember I debuged other apps on this device.
Is that a bug in android studio or my device's software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing "Attach debuger to Android process" button solves my problem and connects dubuger to my app. I just don't know why debugger does not attach when I press "Debug App" Button at first !!!

[image]

[image]